# Xamarin.Forms iOS xcassets folder will auto hidden

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I'm building Xamarin.Forms with Android and iOS. May I know why after "include in project" is set, the folder keeps turn into invisible every time I re-open the project?

[image]

If I open the csproj file, it seems all the assets have auto added the `<Visible>false</Visible>` tag, including individual asset tag. Below image showing "Left - original" and "Right - auto added visible to false after re-open VS"

[image]

I have tested using Visual Studio 2017 and 2019, both behaving in the same manner.

Anybody got a solution? Thanks.

Comment: This usually happens when you have both Mac users and vs users in your team and both of them keep pushing the project files unto your TFS or Git!

Comment: Nope, I'm the only developer

Comment: @teapeng This is the default setting. xcassets is referenced to the Asset Catalogs in your project's solution explorer, you can find your images there.